# How to set ntpd server time without referencing another server?

Tags: debian, c, ntp, ntpd

I have an embedded system which synchronizes UTC locally using NTP. One of the clients in the system acts as time reference for the other clients. I guess you could think of it as stratum 0. A program on this "NTP server" may get a message to set time from one of many potential time sources, such as GPS system or somebody setting a new time through the UI. New time does not come as an actual NTP message on NTP port 123.

I've been searching for a while how to set the ntpd time without success. I'm thinking a `popen()` doing something-something should do the trick, but the internet seems all focused on how to adjust time to external server, not configuring a local system.

How do I set ntpd server time without referencing an external NTP server?

---

As an example use case, the time source may be one of these: [docs.novatel.com/oem7/Content/Home.htm](https://docs.novatel.com/oem7/Content/Home.htm) (a GNSS reciever).  This is just one possible configuration. Other customers use their own separate time sources.  It does not include an NTP server, so I would have to implement one from scratch.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Senior officers says it is the best way to go, and since I'm new to the project it is best to trust their decision. Time is embedded in messages from this: https://docs.novatel.com/oem7/Content/Home.htm It does not include an NTP server, so I would have to implement one from scratch. Which is sort of what I'm doing, I guess?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Also Novatel is just one possible configuration. Other customers use their own separate time sources. Sometimes entered manually through the UI.

Comment: It is a weird idea indeed. In my (quite long) experience in IT I have never seen a business setting up their own stratum 0 NTP server...

Comment: @dr01 Currently reading this: https://serverfault.com/questions/153206/setting-up-a-local-stratum-2-ntp-server apparently I'm not the only one trying to set up a "local" NTP server. (But the post does not tell how to calibrate the master so it is not the same I think…)

Comment: @Andreas Just something to be aware of.  [GPS time is not the same as UTC](https://confluence.qps.nl/qinsy/en/utc-to-gps-time-correction-32245263.html)

Comment: @Andreas Well, if your machines *can never be network connected to the outside* then you need to have an internal time source. But it doesn't seem your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is a much more complicated topic than many people realize.  While it may appear that all you need to do is "set the `ntpd` time", there's actually a lot more to consider.

A really blind (bad) answer to your question might be to simply set the system time using [`clock`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/clock) on the commandline or [`stime`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stime) from a program.  This would work because NTP doesn't store it's own internal clock.  But doing this may not produce the results you actually want.

NTP not only sets the current system time and hands it out to clients, it also tracks errors in the clock allowing it to make adjustments in between polling another time source.  Simply setting the current time won't inform NTP of the error and thus doesn't update the "frequency" used by NTP to make adjustments to the system clock.

If your only source for the real time is someone setting the system time may be your only option.

If you wish to use a GPS as a time source for an `ntpd` server, then the correct term is that you are trying to configure `ntpd` as a [stratum 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_strata) server.

---

Having done some reading on the matter it seems that `ntpd` does have a built-in way to talk to hardware clocks including GPS.  [It's configured using the dummy address range `127.127.0.0/16`](https://serverfault.com/questions/766701/getting-gpsd-address-for-ntpd).  There's an example of this here:

- https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/02/22/how-to-build-a-stratum-1-ntp-server-using-a-raspberry-pi/ with `127.127.20.0`
- https://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html#ntp-conf with `127.127.28.0`

If this too isn't available for you because the time device isn't actually attached to the NTP server box, then you may be able to write your own kernel module to simulate a hardware clock based on the incoming packets.

But your best option by far is to use the drivers others have built for this purpose.  If at all possible you should attach your GNSS receiver to a box actually running ntpd to allow ntpd to get the time automatically whenever it wants.

Comment: Any thoughts about `adjtime()`, `adjtimex()` or `ntp_adjtime()`?

Comment: These are alternatives to `stime()`.  `adjtime` lets you add or subtract an offset rather than specifying an absolute time. `adjtimex` and `ntp_adjtime` both let you set a number of additional parameters inside the kernel (including frequency, max error, etc.).  Calculating these parameters yourself rather than getting `ntpd` to do it for you is *very complicated* and a very long way outside my knowledge.